# Не работает событие click на iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone

Доброго времени суток.
Делал адаптивную версию сайта и, как всегда, нужно было добавить гамбургер.
При клике сделал так, чтобы меню выезжало, но вот на айфонах и сафари не работает.
`cursor: pointer` поставил, `click` на `touchstart` менял, вобщем все советы с интернета перепробовал, но так ничего и не сработал.
Даже если просто прописать:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert()">Клик</a>
```

Не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался в причине. У меня была ф-ция

```
function sendForm(form, form_name='default'){
```

как оказалось из-за `form_name='default'` - падал js на айфонах и сафари, без понятия почему. Переписал ф-цию, все заработало.

Comment: Добавлять дефолтные аргументы в функцию - это новинка для JS (относительно новое, конечно). Если Safari достаточно старая, то ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё вот такой вариант, можно его сделать и без jQuery, но у меня такой необходимости не было:

```
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
    agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/),
    mobileLink = $('.mobile-link'); // Добавить этот класс всем ссылкам, которые должны нажиматься

touchMenuEvent = agentID ? "touchstart" : "click";
mobileLink.bind(touchMenuEvent, function() {
    $(this).click();
});
```